# Excel vba: the same code becomes slow if get properties are added to a class

Tags: vba, excel, class, oop

I have a main sub that makes use of a `Client` class: creates an array with `100 000` `Clients` and loops over the array `100` times, each time setting a different random number to each `Client`.

```
Sub start()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim clientsColl() As Client
    ReDim clientsColl(1 To 100000) As Client

    For j = 1 To 100000
        Set clientsColl(j) = New Client
        clientsColl(j).setClientName = "Client_" & j

        Application.StatusBar = "Getting client " & j

        DoEvents
    Next

    Dim clientCopy As Variant
    For i = 1 To 100
        For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
            clientCopy.generateRandom
        Next

        Application.StatusBar = "Calculating " & i

        DoEvents
    Next

    MsgBox ("done")

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Client class:

```
Option Explicit

Private clientname As String
Private identityNumber As String
Private creditRating As String

Private contractTenor As Long
Private contractNumber As String
Private contractRate As Double

Private totalReserves As Double
Private totalReservesRate As Double

Private debtType As String
Private totalDebt As Double

Private lossRatio As Double
Private totalLoss As Variant
Private totalProfit As Double

Private totalPd As Double
Private totalLgd As Double

Private simulationCount As Long
Private randomNumber As Double
Private outcome As Integer

Private loss As Double
Private profit As Double

Private sumLosses() As Double
Private sumProfits() As Double
Private sumResults() As Double

Private averageDebtInfo As Double

Public Sub generateRandom()
    randomNumber = Rnd()
End Sub

Public Property Get getClientName()
    getClientName = clientName
End Property

Public Property Let setClientName(value As String)
    clientName = value
End Property
```

However, this code takes different time to run, depending whether the `Client` class has the `Get` and `Let` properties or not. The current version of the class posted above runs in about `25` seconds. If I add several `Get` properties to get things like `identityNumber` or `contractRate` it would take about `1 minute 25 seconds`.

Why does adding simple `Get` properties affect the code so much? Can anything be done about it? I can't afford this code to run any more than 30 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following codes to disable your application features while running the macro.

**References:**

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1035
https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/speed-up-VBA-macro-with-these-subroutines/

```
Sub SpeedOff()
     'Turns on the time wasters
     With Application
         .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
         .ScreenUpdating = True
         .EnableEvents = True
         .DisplayAlerts = True
         .Cursor = xlDefault
         .StatusBar = False
         .EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
     End With
End Sub

Sub SpeedOn()
    'Turns off the time wasters
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Cursor = xlWait
        .EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is definitely helpful information, but it doesn’t help answer the question of why do the stated changes affect overall execution time.